# How to check a specific checkbox in a pure CSS Accordion via URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, accordion

I use a pure CSS Accordion to present my content. The Accordion works with normal checkboxes. Now I want to implement, that by sending a simple link, a single checkbox entry will be checked and with the help of an anchor the browser should jump to that entry and show the specific content to the reader.

The whole thing should be done preferably without a scripting or programming language, but after a lot of research I think that at least JavaScript will be required (it must run on the client side, so no PHP or similar).

I have searched and tested a lot but unfortunately I have not found any suitable solution that would work.

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My example Website</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>

body {
font-size: 21px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
max-width: 550px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: black;
}
input {
display: none;
}
label {
display: block;    
padding: 8px 22px;
margin: 0 0 1px 0;
cursor: pointer;
background: #181818;
border: 1px solid white;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #FFF;
position: relative;
}
label:hover {
background: white;
border: 1px solid white;
color:black;
}
label::after {
content: '+';
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 2px;
}
input:checked + label::after {
content: '-';
right: 14px;
top: 3px;
}
.content {
background: #DBEECD;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #DBEECD, #EBD1CD);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #DBEECD, #EBD1CD);
background: linear-gradient(to top left, #DBEECD, #EBD1CD);
padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
margin: 0 0 1px 0;
border-radius: 1px;
}
input + label + .content {
display: none;
}
input:checked + label + .content {
display: block;
}
</style>

<input type="checkbox" id="title1" name="contentbox" />
<label for="title1">Content 1</label>

<div class="content">

  My Content 1

</div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="title2" name="contentbox" />
<label for="title2">Content 2</label>

<div class="content">

  My Content 2

</div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="title3" name="contentbox" />
<label for="title3">Content 3</label>

<div class="content">

  My Content 3

</div>

</body>
</html>
```
````

Comment: you should write some code you tried to solve your problem, and we can help you

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve] with valid HTML

Comment: I have now updated some of my CSS so that my issue is easier to understand. I want to access and open (for example) "Content 3" just by clicking a link. And i have not found any code that would work to solve this issue, so i can not provide an example code. I only use a little bit JS on my website to open and close all checkboxes (because I have many of them) but this would not help me in this case.

Comment: Have you considered using a [`<details>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)?

Comment: A belated demo to demonstrate the suggested use of the `<details>` element: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h0Lqzvbp/

Comment: Even though it would be a lot of work to redesign the whole accordion (which I would definitely do if it was worth it), this variant with the <details> element doesn't work either. I have tried to set an anchor at title 3 (both in the example text and at title 3) but in none of the variants it is possible to access the text with the help of a link so that it opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that JavaScript is required. I have provided a solution, but I haven't tested it, because it's not possible to test in the snippet. It should select the relevant checkbox when a hash tag is detected in the URL that corresponds with a checkbox ID.

So you would use some time `https://www.website.com/#title1`

```js
// Check if URL of browwser window has hash tag
if (location.hash) {
  // Get URL hash tag
  const hash = window.location.hash;
  // Select checkbox with ID of hashtag
  const checkbox = document.querySelector(hash);
  // Check if checkbox exists
  if(checkbox) {
    // Set selected checkbox as checked
    checkbox.checked = true;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: block;    
  padding: 8px 22px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #181818;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}
label:hover {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color:black;
}
label::after {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 2px;
}
input:checked + label::after {
  content: '-';
  right: 14px;
  top: 3px;
}
.content {
  background: #DBEECD;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #DBEECD, #EBD1CD);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #DBEECD, #EBD1CD);
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, #DBEECD, #EBD1CD);
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
input + label + .content {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label + .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="title1" name="contentbox" />
<label for="title1">Content 1</label>

<div class="content">
  My Content 1
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="title2" name="contentbox" />
<label for="title2">Content 2</label>

<div class="content">
  My Content 2
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="title3" name="contentbox" />
<label for="title3">Content 3</label>

<div class="content">
  My Content 3
</div>
```

Comment: The code sounds very good, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I even tried it with a single test file where everything was in one place (HTML, CSS and the JS) but it doesn't work there either. The selected checkbox is just not opening.

I have also tried different types of links, but none of them activates the desired checkbox.

https://www.website.com/#title1
https://www.website.com/index.html#title1

Comment: @KiBLS I just tested this locally and it worked, so I'm unsure what is going on :(

Comment: Hm, this is very strange... I uploaded it now to a server but it doesn't work for me. Do I have an error somewhere in the code? But i copy and paste only your code? Or why does it not work for me but for you it works? http://kibls.freecluster.eu/test.html Can you click on show source code and tell me where the error is? Because no matter which URL I try, the checkboxes remain closed/unchecked. :/

Comment: @KiBLS Move the script to just before the closing of the body. The script is loading before the dom has loaded. I've also adjusted the conditional statement that checks if the checkbox exists, because it was causing an error when it couldn't find the checkbox.

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the mistake. It showed that I'm a complete JS beginner. In this way also your old code worked now... Thank you so much! But now I still have a problem! In this example, the accordion was very small with 3 entries. But let's assume the accordion has 30-50 entries and I want to open for example entry number 20. Thanks to your code, the entry number 20 will be opened, but the browser will not jump to the position of the opened entry. So the reader does not know that something has been opened below. Do you have a possible solution for that too? :)

Comment: @KiBLS It should already jump to it. Using a # at the end of a link is an anchor link and it will jump to the element with the relevant ID.

Comment: @KiBLS You won't currently see that happening in the demo you made, because the window has no where to scroll to.

Comment: Hm, no... the browser remains motionless, only the checkbox is opened. Here I have now inserted the JS as an external file (of course at the bottom) and it works great so far. The code is opening entry number 20 but as I said the browser does not move the view to that entry. http://kibls.freecluster.eu/#title20 Hm, with window.scrollTo(300, 500); we could move the opened entry into view, but if there were (for example) 50 entries, the positions would have to adjust. So there must be another command/code for this? :/

Comment: @KiBLS Ok I see. It's because the inputs are set to `display: none`. Remove that style from the inputs and do some like `position: absolute; left: -100vw;` to hide them offscreen.

Comment: It works now as desired. Thank you so much! I will integrate everything immediately and upload it. Thanks again and have a great day! :)